# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, media, audio-recording

I want to implement audio recording functionality in my angular app using media recorder but I am getting the following error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'

Does anyone has solution for this.

Comment: Please give us more code (for example you must include file) to have a chance to debug your code. It was great if you share your code in some public place, where we will have a chance to run and change original code

Comment: Which media library are you using. Have you imported the modules and all the needed things to the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [Media Recorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

Go to your tsconfig file if you dont have one create by `npx tsc --init`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ......your other options
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]
  }
}
```